# Why is energy not conserved instantaneously in electromagnetic waves?

Tags: energy, waves, electromagnetic-radiation, energy-conservation

I don't know if its a valid question but it's been bugging me for a while so I'll ask it.
I know that the Poynting Vector $\vec{S}$ gives the intensity of the electromagnetic wave, and its related to the electric and magnetic fields by $\vec S=\frac{\vec E \times \vec B}{\mu}$, where $E=E_0\cos(kx-\omega t)\hat{j}$, $B=B_0\cos(kx-\omega t)\hat{k}$ and $\mu$ is the permeability of free space. I see that on performing the cross product, energy is phase dependent. 
Is this not a violation to energy conservation?
I understand that energy on an average is conserved, but I think that energy should  be conserved instantaneously(there is no source or sink, its just vacuum). This isn't something specific to EM waves. If the energy oscillates, where does the energy go when it reduces from its maximum, and where does it come from when increasing from the minimum? Shouldn't it "stay inside" the wave?

Comment: Poynting vector gives the *energy flux*, not the energy density. Overall, *Poynting theorem* describes *instantaneous energy conservation*.

Answer (score 5):

The energy *is* conserved instantaneously, not just on average. The statement of conservation of electromagnetic energy is [Poynting's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poynting%27s_theorem) whose differential form in vacuum is
$$-\frac{\partial}{\partial t} \left(\frac{1}{2}\epsilon_0E^2+\frac{1}{2}\mu_0H^2\right)=\vec \nabla \cdot (\vec E\times\vec H)+\vec J \cdot \vec E.$$

The Poynting vector is not the energy density, it gives the flow of electromagnetic energy per unit area per unit time. Even if the energy density oscillates, that still does not mean energy is not conserved instantaneously, because it will be accompanied by an oscillating Poynting vector and/or work term $\vec J \cdot \vec E$. Likewise the fact that $\vec S = \vec E \times \vec H$ is time dependent and oscillatory doesn't mean energy is not conserved instantaneously. If $\vec \nabla \cdot \vec S$ is time dependent, the other terms will have the same time dependence to make Poynting's theorem work out.